# Subtract data between two tables in SQLite android database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have two data tables in one database named **my_store.db**. The first table name is **stock_table** and the second table is **sell_table**.
The first table has 4 columns.

stock table

| code | name | price | total stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Books | 500 | 200 |
| 2 | pen | 10 | 500 |
| 3 | Reading table | 1000 | 20 |

sell table

| code | name | sell_qty | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Books | 10 | 1-02-2015 8:00:36 GMT |
| 2 | pen | 50 | 1-02-2015 8:02:45 GMT |
| 3 | Reading table | 5 | 1-02-2015 8:33:32 GMT |
| 1 | Books | 5 | 1-02-2015 9:04:15 GMT |
| 2 | pen | 15 | 1-02-2015 9:23:32 GMT |
| 1 | Books | 4 | 1-02-2015 10:43:18 GMT |

So when the user sells one product stock table will update immediately. user is selling one product many times. so I get the same product code in the sell table.
how to get the last sell record and subtract from the main stock amount.

What result I want

| code | name | price | total stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Books | 500 | 81 |
| 2 | pen | 10 | 435 |
| 3 | Reading table | 1000 | 15 |

I am working in SQLite database. It's an android app.

Comment: you can use sql update statements

Comment: In update how I will subtract others table value.

Comment: read the value and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the subquery will help you here

```
update stock_table
   set total_stock = total_stock - (select sum(sell_quantity) 
                                      from sell_table st 
                                     where product_code = st.product_code)
```

the sum() function is here in case if there might be more than one line in sell_table for each product. You can replace it with sell_quantity if you're sure there won't be more that one record per product.

Additionaly, if you need to update total_stock for one product only, you may add a where clause:

```
update stock_table
   set total_stock = total_stock - (select sum(sell_quantity) 
                                      from sell_table st 
                                     where product_code = st.product_code)
 where product_code = 101
```

Comment: look I use this don't get the right result. `public void stockUpdate(String code) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(" UPDATE STORE_PRODUCT_DATABASE SET STOCK = STOCK - (SELECT SUM(SELL_QTY) FROM STORE_SELL_DATABASE SSD WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = SSD.PRODUCT_CODE )" + " WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = ? ",new String[] {code});
    }`    Problem is if my one product stock is 100 after sell 5 pcs its stock showing 73 pcs or some weird result. what to do

Comment: @user16582711 please check what this query "select sum(sell_quantity) 
                                      from sell_table st 
                                     where product_code = your_product_goes_here" returns?

Comment: @user16582711 unfortunately markup doesn't work here, but from what I see I can assume you've execute not the query I asked for. The subquery should return only 1 value in only 1 row, whereas the result from you shows 3 columns and many lines. Please execute the subqiery from my last comment for a product_code and let me know the results.

Comment: sorry. I am new to the database. So I am confused. Look I edit my question. Maybe it will clarify what I want.

Comment: I HAVE DONE IT.                                                                  
UPDATE STORE_PRODUCT_DATABASE SET STOCK = STOCK - (SELECT SELL_QTY FROM STORE_SELL_DATABASE SSD ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)" + " WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = ?

Comment: @sadik that's good. Sorry, I just came to your previous comment. So you're taking just the last selling event, now it's clear, thanks